# Redirect wordpress links within a single category

Tags: wordpress, redirect, categories

I need to redirect links on a wordpress site to a new wordpress site.

I realize there are plugins and whatnot that do this, and if I have to go that route I will.

I need to redirect individual posts to their new version on the new site.

I have hundreds of posts to redirect, and would most likely end up needing to edit the redirects individually which could take some time. So I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to just redirect all posts within one category.

All the posts within this one category are now published on a separate site - same slugs.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to replace (redirect) the url on all posts in a category with the new url, while keeping the slugs so the post links redirect to their new version on the new site.